# Manually clear facebook token in Facebook Login 4.4 for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

Using facebook login version 2.4, with the FacebookCoreSDK iOS 4.4. Seems like version 4 has removed all manual session management features. The app I'm working on has a logout feature in which I would like to manually clear out the facebook access token.

Previously in 3.x I could do it like this:

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

I can't find an equivalent in 4.x.... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FBSDKLoginManager` `logOut` method.

> This calls `[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil]`
>   and `[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil]`.

reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/

example:

```
[[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut];
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's something like [[FBSDKLogin new] logout];

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)facebookClick:(id)sender {
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
     [login logOut];
    login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error)
        {
                 NSLog(@"Process error");
             //   [login logOut];
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            // [login logOut];
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
             [self getUserInformation];
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question not only for this person, but for readers in the future, who might not know why your code is the way it is.